# Spark Configuration: memory/instance/cores

Tags: apache-spark

Lately I have found myself a bit confused between the different SPARK settings `spark.executor.memory`, `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`, `SPARK_MEM`, `SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY`, and the relationship to `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES` and `SPARK_WORKER_CORES`

I found this post but it does not discuss SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY
[Spark Configuration: SPARK_MEM vs. SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171686/spark-configuration-spark-mem-vs-spark-worker-memory)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all just few words about terms.
Spark master is application that coordinates resources allocation from slaves. Master does not perform any computations. Master is just resource manager.

Spark worker is application on worker node which coordinates resources on given worker node.

Spark executor is application created by spark worker which performs tasks on worker node for driver.

Check this doc for additional details - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

`spark.executor.memory` - is amount of memory for executor. This memory used for given user task.

SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY - how much system memory can be used by worker to creating executors on node. For example you have 64gb on node. You set SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY to 60gb. This means that you can create 2 x 30g executors or 10 x 6gb executors and so on.

SPARK_MEM AFAIK is not used anymore. I can not find it in current docs

SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY is memory for master. Should not be to high :)

SPARK_WORKER_CORES is total number of cores to be used by executors by each worker

SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES is number of workers per worker node.

All these parameters are described here - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Comment: Thanks @1esha, if SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY = 60gb, and we want 2 executors then should spark.executor.memory = 30g, or will that be automatically set? or can spark.executor.memory be set to something else like 10g and will SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY then be changed to 20g with 2 executors?

Comment: Oscar, SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY is total memory for executors per node. If you have two nodes with 64gb each and want to spent up to 60gb per node for spark executors set SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY to 60gb. This allocate 60gb per node for executors. Next, in you driver you may set `spark.executor.memory`. It specify how much memory per node allocate from SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY. If you set it to 10gb it takes 20gb total - 10 gb from each node.